# How websites discover subdomains using only 'A' DNS records

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain, reverse-dns, domain-name

Don't 'A' records only return IPv4 addresses?

Why do some websites return subdomains? How do they find those subdomains? I mean, are they doing normal subdomain bruteforcing then resolve each subdomain's A record?

Examples of those websites: DNSDumpster.com => Under 'A' Host Records section

and this one as well https://hackertarget.com/find-dns-host-records/

For example, when looking for uber.com, it returns the following list of subdomains: 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rqxM.png)

Does that mean that it tries to match whatever entries having the string uber.com ocurence and returns its corresponding IPv4 address in the DNS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the pages for the links you posted.

Short answer: brute force & big data.
Long answer: “The data we use to find host records here at hackertarget.com is sourced from a number of excellent projects as well as Internet search engines.”